# Identify if user has OneDrive and change file path accordingly

Tags: excel, vba, windows-10, office365, onedrive

I have the following `VBAs` to save an Excel workbook on the desktop of the User. 
The first one is used if the User does not have `OneDrive`. 
The second one is used if the User has `OneDrive`.

```
Sub Without_OneDrive()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\firstname.lastname\Desktop\Test.xlsm"
End Sub

Sub With_OneDrive()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\firstname.lastname\OneDrive - limango.com\Desktop\Test.xlsm"
End Sub
```

All this works fine.

---

However, now I have the situation that some users have `OneDrive` and other ones don't. 
 Therefore, I am wondering if there is a solution to identify if the user has `OneDrive` or not and then decide which `file path` should be used. Something like this:

```
Sub SaveWorkbook()
If OneDrive exist then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\firstname.lastname\OneDrive - limango.com\Desktop\Test.xlsm"
Else
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\firstname.lastname\Desktop\Test.xlsm"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done, using the `Dir` VBA function, as you can see in the following source code excerpt:

```
Public Function DirExists() as Boolean

Dim DirName As String

    DirName = VBA.FileSystem.Dir("C:\Users\firstname.lastname\OneDrive - limango.com", vbDirectory)

    If DirName = VBA.Constants.vbNullString Then
        DirExists = False
    Else
        DirExists = True
    End If

End Sub
```

For your information, I got this piece of code from [this URL](https://www.xelplus.com/excel-vba-check-if-file-folder-exists-dir/).

Comment: I tried on my computer. I do have OneDrive for sure so the path must exist but the code does not find it.

Comment: @Michi: you're right: I had forgotten to put the `, vbDirectory`. I've adapted my code, now it should be working.